# jquery mouse events conflict?

Tags: jquery, mouseevent

I'm trying to do a drag and scroll on one of my divs "album", which is a list of images.

Here's what I did

```
$(album).on({
    mousedown:function(){
        console.log('mousedown');
        $(album).on('mousemove', function(){
            console.log('mousemove')
        })
    }

    mouseup:function(){
        console.log('mouseup');
        $(album).off('mousemove');
    }

})
```

What's happening here is that after mouse down, it will trace out 'mousemove' about 4 or 5 times then it would stop tracing, and a little no action icon showed up with a transparent version of the image I clicked on. Then if I let go the mouse here, it wouldn't trace out 'mouseup'. But if I click on the div and not move my mouse then let go, it will trace out 'mouseup'.

Why wouldn't console continue to trace out mouse move and why didn't it trace out mouseup? Thanks.

Comment: I have a fully working example for you :)

Comment: You have any luck with this man?

Comment: I have a theory, the error in the code above is due to the fact that the click event only fires once and you wanted a sustained state on the mousemove.  VIDesign solved this by preventing the default behavior of the click event and I solved this by creating a dependency for the mousemove event.  It is up to you which answer you prefer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go man!  Perfect!!

Working [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/videsignz/cfBQj/)

**HTML**

```
<div class='album'></div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$('body').on('mousedown', '.album', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('mousedown');

    $(this).on('mousemove', function(){
       console.log('mousemove');
    });

    $(this).on('mouseup', function(){
       $(this).off('mousemove');
       console.log('mouseup');  
     });

});
```

Comment: thanks so much! But why do I have to prevent the default action to make this work?

Comment: @shibbydoo Your welcome!! I can't say for sure...When I tested your original, I was getting the mousemove log on every other mousedown, so I assume there is interference from the mousedown/mouseup with the standard click function.  This is just speculation.  I'm sure we could figure it out if we logged all mouse events to see how they truly react to each other. But for now, I would say 'take what you can get' on this one! :)

Answer (score 0):

What if we go about it in a different way:

```
var itIsClicked;

$(album).on("mousedown", function(){
    itIsClicked = true;
});

$(album).on('mousemove', function(){
    if(itIsClicked) {
        console.log('mousemove');
    }
});

$(album).on("mouseup", function(){
    itIsClicked = false;
});
```

Nesting events, while it seems to make sense, can run into the kind of trouble you have described.  Although I'd love to hear any theories as to why it is not working for you.

Comment: It seems if we prevent default on the click actions, it cleans up. When I was messing with my answer above, without prevent default, it worked the first time you click, drag, release, but then it flipped the functions somehow.  When you clicked, it wouldn't work, but when you moved the mouse without holding the button, it would register the mouse move.  Can't really explain why though.

Comment: I've tested both of our answers and it seems they each works.  We will have to run test to see which answers should be accepted.